# Consuming SOAP web service, "The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials."

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, x509certificate2

I am struggling with consuming SOAP 1.2 web service over HTTPS where I have to authenticate using a certificate. So I received *.p12 (PKCS12) client certificate (issued to COMPANY, issued by DOMAIN.COM), which is signed by the issuer (issued to DOMAIN.COM, issued by DOMAIN.COM).

My app.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="DistributorServiceBinding">
                  <security authenticationMode="AnonymousForCertificate">
                    <issuedTokenParameters />
                    <localClientSettings />
                    <localServiceSettings />
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                  </security>
                  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                  <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://subdomain.domain.com/*/*/*"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="DistributorServiceBinding"
                contract="*" name="DistributorServicePort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I am trying to put some data through web service, I am getting the following error:

> The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate
>   in ServiceCredentials

And here I have the first problem:

- Which certificate should I set here? Is is the one, which I imported from *.p12 file or it is a completely different certificate, which I should get from the service owner?
- If the data is sent one way - I am only sending the data, but not getting it - can I turn off serviceCertificate validation?

I tried to use the certificate from my *.p12 file, which is issued to DOMAIN.COM and is signing my client certificate, but then, I am getting this error:

> Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity
>   of the remote endpoint was 'SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM' but the remote
>   endpoint provided DNS claim 'DOMAIN.COM'. If this is a legitimate
>   remote endpoint, you can fix the problem by explicitly specifying DNS
>   identity 'DOMAIN.COM' as the Identity property of EndpointAddress when
>   creating channel proxy.

And here is my second problem:

- Should I use the mentioned certificate as a serviceCertificate? Should it be issued to SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM or *.DOMAIN.COM instead of DOMAIN.COM, so is it WS owner mistake?
- Should I ask for a certificate, which is issued to *.DOMAIN.COM and is used by the owner on service side?

I will be extremely grateful for any help!